# In Salesforce Whats the difference between Page Layouts and Visual force Pages?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, page-layout

I have created a custom Object in Salesforce. Now to save values in that what should i use Page layouts or a visualforce page and apex controller? in other way- When should we use page layouts and when the visualforce pages should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Page layout** is a built-in standard mechanism for displaying information to user. You can use Page layout editor without any development experience, just drag-and-drop. If you need a simple form which just shows field value and related records you have to use a page layout. But sometimes you need  to use JavaScript, custom HTML tags, CSS on you page in this case you have to use **VisulaForce** pages which are similar to JSF or any similar technologies. Also note that you can include VisualForce inside standard page layouts.

Comment: Got it now,Thanks Pavel